# Blue Prism HTML Spy Element issue (doesn't exist)

Tags: html, automation, spy, blueprism

I've just installed Blue Prism. When I create an object and enter into Application Modeler, I click launch, spy element, and there are only three options: Win 32, Accessibility, Region. I know there are a lot more, but I am only interested in HTML mode. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

To spy elements using html mode, then you need to use an object that is set as "Browser-based Application" in application modeller.

The simplest method to achieve that, would be if you follow the guide below:

1. Create a new object
2. Click on Applcation Modeller icon
3. On the first screen of wizard choose "Define a new application model"
4. On the second screen of wizard choose "Browser-based Application".

Then the HTML-mode should be available for use.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't even let me Spy the element. When I click to Attach, the application launch but I can't spy anything because the button returns to "Attach". Y tried to double-click on it very fast, and I access the Spy Elements but can't click it, and I have to stop the program with the task admin. Again, in the elements it doesn't appear the HTML one.

Comment: Could you please open the application modeller and check what you have written in second and third field? 


Its names are "Enter the window title of the target aplication" and "Enter the windows process name of the target application".


For the troubleshooting purposes i'd write simple asteriks (*) symbol in both 2nd and 3rd field. Could you please tell me if you are able to attach then?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the HTML Spy Mode works only on Internet Explorer browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was to change the parameters specifically, Child Index in attach Stage (navigate) Appearently i was attaching to a different iexplore. Changing it from 1 to 0 solved it for me. I was able to see HTML Spying mode.
[Attach Navigation Stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwSzd.png)
Hope it helps